# Scandir For Directories Above

Tags: php, scandir

have a website that is obviously in the root of my server. I am now making a web app, which lies in `m/iphone/`. All was going well but my website uses `scandir()` with all of the files in a folder on the root of my server.

How can I access these files from when I'm inside the `m/iphone` directory?

Sorry if it's a really obvious answer, I'm a complete beginner.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `..` which stands for back in terms of folders, in your case you should run something like this:

```
scandir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

You should play with `..` in path name:

```
scandir(dirname(__FILE__).'../anotherfolder'); //go back one folder and go to folder 'anotherfolder'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For some reason I had to change this to scandir(dirname(__FILE__).'/../anotherfolder');